# Xubuntu 18.04 LTS Ristretto does not open image.ascii.pgm files

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, image-viewers, ristretto

The default viewer for any image in Xubuntu is Ristretto Image Viewer.
Using Xubuntu 16.04 LTS, it was possible to read `image.ascii.pgm` with Ristretto. With 18.04 the program opens but no images are displayed.

**Questions**:

- Is there a way of reading `image.ascii.pgm` files with the Ristretto Image Viewer in Xubuntu 18.04 LTS?
- If not, do you suggest to use another viewer instead? If so, how to use another viewer as default?

**Temporary workaround**: I can read the images using Inkscape, but, as you can imagine, it is not a light-weight viewer program; it is a heavy vector-graphics image editor (like shooting a fly with a cannon).

> ASCII PGM (Portable Gray Map) format for 2D grayscale graphics information. More info [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/pgma_io/pgma_io.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **For your first question:** There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ristretto/+bug/1771227) on this issue. It seems that it is fixed in the 0.8.4 version.
- **For your second question:** I am highly recommending [nomacs](https://www.google.com/search?q=nomacs&oq=nomacs&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i60.1519j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) image viewer. You can install it by running:

  ```
    sudo apt install nomacs
  ```

  To set it as default for a specific file type, <kbd>right-click</kbd> the file you want to have opened with nomacs, then *Properties...* → *Open With:* → *nomacs*.